# Placing AD Administrators in to /etc/sudoers

Tags: linux, windows, active-directory

I've added the following to /etc/sudoers:

```
%DOMAIN\\domain\ admins       ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

When I log in to use the administrator account I get this:

```
[administrator@internal.mydomain.com@plex ~]$ sudo yum update -y
[sudo] password for administrator@internal.mydomain.com:
administrator@internal.mydomain.com is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

I would like my AD Admins to be full root users on linux servers.

I am using REALMD to connect my Linux machines to AD.

Comment: Are your AD groups displayed when you run "getent group"?

Comment: No. I only get local groups.

Comment: Well that's why your sudo command is failing. You'll need to investigate why your Linux systems don't know about your AD groups. Once you resolve that, the sudo issue will likely be resolved as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `getent users` and `getent groups` do not show AD users and groups, you either aren't correctly joined to AD or you have a misconfiguration somewhere (maybe in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`).   If you can't see the box joined to AD, I would try rejoining and testing with `kinit` 
[as described here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Windows_Integration_Guide/realmd-domain.html) and see if that resolves your issue.